# C#: Grouping/Subgrouping Payment By Type, Year, Month

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I'm implementing a Payment Report and keep butting my head against the wall. The Back-end is SQL Server and the Payment Table is set-up as:

```
PaymentId |    Date    |  Type  | Misc Fields
0          2000-08-10    cash     ...
25         2019-08-05    web CC   ...
26         2019-08-05    cash     ...
27         2019-08-05    cash     ...
28         2019-08-05    check    ...
29         2019-07-10    cash     ...
```

I'm trying to use C#'s LINQ to read the Payment table, then apply the grouping; such that the results fall into the following:

- 1st Level: Type
- 2nd Level: PaymentDate.Year
- 3rd Level: PaymentDate.Month

```
cash
   2000
      08
         Payment 0 Details
   2019
      07
         Payment 29 Details
      08
         Payment 26
         Payment 27
check
   2019
      08
         Payment 28
web CC
   2019
      08
         Payment 25
```

I've tried several approaches, but the closest that I've gotten is either grouped by Type/Month or Type/Year.

I stumbled upon (no joke intended)
[Ms's Create a Nested Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/create-a-nested-group)

Which is what I tried to base the following code (results in Type/Month Grouping) off of:

```
var ranges = new List<String> { "Cash", "Check", "Money Order", "Web CC" };

var groupedPayments = from payment in allPayments
                                  let match = ranges.FirstOrDefault(range => range.Equals(payment.PaymentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                  group payment by !String.IsNullOrEmpty(match) ? match : "Other" into TypeBracket
                                  from payment2 in (
                                       from pay in TypeBracket
                                       group pay by pay.PaymentDate.Year into TypedYearBracket
                                       from payment3 in (
                                           from pay2 in TypedYearBracket
                                           group pay2 by pay2.PaymentDate.Month into MonthBracket
                                           select MonthBracket
                                       )
                                       select payment3
                                  )
                                  group payment2 by TypeBracket.Key;
```

Simplified Code for Console Application

Payment Class Definition

```
public class Payment 
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
        public String PaymentType { get; set; }

        public Payment(int id, DateTime date, string type)
        {
            PaymentId = id;
            PaymentDate = date;
            PaymentType = type;
        }
}
```

Main

```
public class PaymentExample 
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Payment> allPayments = new List<Payment>()
            {
                new Payment(25, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "web CC"),
                new Payment(26, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "cash"),
                new Payment(27, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "cash"),
                new Payment(28, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "check"),
                new Payment(29, new DateTime(2019, 7, 10), "cash"),
                new Payment(0, new DateTime(2000, 8, 10), "cash")
            };

            var ranges = new List<String> { "Cash", "Check", "Money Order", "Web CC" };

            var groupedPayments = from payment in allPayments
                                  let match = ranges.FirstOrDefault(range => range.Equals(payment.PaymentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                  group payment by !String.IsNullOrEmpty(match) ? match : "Other" into TypeBracket
                                  from payment2 in (
                                       from pay in TypeBracket
                                       group pay by pay.PaymentDate.Year into TypedYearBracket
                                       from payment3 in (
                                           from pay2 in TypedYearBracket
                                           group pay2 by pay2.PaymentDate.Month into MonthBracket
                                           select MonthBracket
                                       )
                                       select payment3
                                  )
                                  group payment2 by TypeBracket.Key;

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");// Note I'm checking the output by using a breakpoint on this line. However, I can add further code if necessary
        }
}
```

*** Too long to comment on jdweng's post
Um, I guess I'm missing something. I added

```
foreach (var x in results)
            {
                foreach (var y in x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}, Year: {1}, Month: {2}, ID: {3}", y.PaymentType, y.PaymentDate.Year, y.PaymentDate.Month, y.PaymentId);
                }

            }
```

to the end of your main function to see what printed. It appears to be grouping by the anonymous type {type, month}, but that results in

```
Type: web CC, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 25
Type: cash, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 26
Type: cash, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 27
Type: check, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 28
Type: cash, Year: 2019, Month: 7, ID: 29
```

Note: that the types aren't grouped together and it completely ignores year (Pointless in the initial example, but the actual data set would contain dates back to 2000) I've updated it to show an example with a payment in 2000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following.  Picture show "Cash" instead of "Type" :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> order = new List<string>() {"web CC", "cash", "check"};


            List<Payment> allPayments = new List<Payment>()
            {
                new Payment(25, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "web CC"),
                new Payment(26, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "cash"),
                new Payment(27, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "cash"),
                new Payment(28, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "check"),
                new Payment(29, new DateTime(2019, 7, 10), "cash")
            };


            var groups = allPayments
                .OrderBy(x => order.IndexOf(x.PaymentType))
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.PaymentDate)
                .GroupBy(x => new { type = x.PaymentType, month = new DateTime(x.PaymentDate.Year, x.PaymentDate.Month, 1) })
                .ToList();

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                foreach(Payment payment in group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type : '{0}', Year : {1}, Month : '{2}', Id : '{3}'", payment.PaymentType, payment.PaymentDate.Year.ToString(), payment.PaymentDate.Month.ToString(), payment.PaymentId);
                }
            }


        }
    }
    public class Payment
    {
        public int PaymentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
        public String PaymentType { get; set; }

        public Payment(int id, DateTime date, string type)
        {
            PaymentId = id;
            PaymentDate = date;
            PaymentType = type;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Again a tentative code-only answer. Please bear in mind that Stack Overflow's mission is to build a web knowledge base for *all* developers. Therefore, a brief explanation of the essential solution helps later readers —the main audience— to actually *learn* something from your answer. These later readers can't "try", only OP can, and won't get excited by trial and error. I think many of your answers have great potential. Just make it stand out better!

Comment: I only added one instruction.  Not very complicated that requires an explanation.

Comment: Hey could you check the edit to my initial post. I'm not seeing this as grouping by type, then year, then month (i.e. All payments are grouped by Type then sub-grouped by year then finally sub-grouped by month)

Comment: You can order by type and then month to get the order you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't -1 btw. I guess I'm missing how grouping by month would group it by years as well. When I ran, your code the groupings didn't appear correct to me. If they are and I'm missing it, could you possibly explain why? I don't mean to beat a dead horse, but two cash payments from the same month (August for example), but differing years (say 2018 and 2019) should by ordered by cash, then year, then month and shouldn't appear in the same month sub-group as they are separated in the year sub-group.

Comment: @jdweng *I only added one instruction*  But only you know where and why. Others have to scrutinize two blocks of code to see the difference. Most people won't do that and hence not appreciate your answer for what it is. And a suggestion to try something strictly isn't even an answer. (Not my dv either, by the way)

Comment: This does appear to solve it! Thanks for expanding upon it, your explanation, and time! I'm going to mess around with it some just to make sure, but I think it's correct. I upvoted (my rep's too low so it doesn't appear) and will accept this as the answer. It'd be great for others that come in with less context if you could add some reasoning to the post though :D

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it! This may be specific to my own setup here, but I figured that I would share the solution for anyone that may stumble across this. First off though, I wanted to thank jdweng for giving me some of his time and to all that viewed it and may be working on it at this moment! If you see something wrong (or that could be improved) with my answer; please feel free to comment or post your own answer for any one that comes along!

After looking at it for a while (too long imo lol), I realized that

```
   from payment3 in (
      from pay2 in TypedYearBracket
      group pay2 by pay2.PaymentDate.Month into MonthBracket
      select MonthBracket
   )
   select payment3
```

was causing an issue with the grouping and pretty much erasing my attempt to group by Year.

I then realized that the last group by of the entire LINQ section (`group payment2 by TypeBracket.Key;` was re-applying the Type grouping to the results of the inner groups. This led me to realize that instead of `select payment3`; I needed `group payment3 by TypedYearBracket.Key` to re-apply the Year grouping to the Month sub-grouping results.

This ends up making the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Payment> allPayments = new List<Payment>()
            {
                new Payment(25, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "web CC"),
                new Payment(26, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "cash"),
                new Payment(27, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "cash"),
                new Payment(28, new DateTime(2019, 8, 5), "check"),
                new Payment(29, new DateTime(2019, 7, 10), "cash"),
                new Payment(0, new DateTime(2000, 8, 10), "cash")
            };

           var ranges = new List<String> { "Cash", "Check", "Money Order", "Web CC" };

           var results = from payment in allPayments
                         let match = ranges.FirstOrDefault(range => range.Equals(payment.PaymentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                         group payment by !String.IsNullOrEmpty(match) ? match : "Other" into TypeBracket
                         from payment2 in (
                            from pay in TypeBracket
                            group pay by pay.PaymentDate.Year into TypedYearBracket
                            from payment3 in (
                                  from pay2 in TypedYearBracket
                                  group pay2 by pay2.PaymentDate.Month into MonthBracket
                                  select MonthBracket
                            )
                            group payment3 by TypedYearBracket.Key
                         )
                         group payment2 by TypeBracket.Key;
            foreach (var x in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1st Level: {0} - {1}", x.Key, x.Count());
                foreach (var y in x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   2nd Level: {0} - {1}", y.Key, y.Count());
                    foreach (var z in y)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("      3rd Level: {0} - {1}", z.Key, z.Count());
                        foreach (var a in z)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("         Details: Type: {0}, Year: {1}, Month: {2}, ID: {3}", a.PaymentType, a.PaymentDate.Year, a.PaymentDate.Month, a.PaymentId);
                        }

                    }
                }
        }
    }
    public class Payment
    {
        public int PaymentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
        public String PaymentType { get; set; }

        public Payment(int id, DateTime date, string type)
        {
            PaymentId = id;
            PaymentDate = date;
            PaymentType = type;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the desired result of:

```
1st Level: Web CC - 1
   2nd Level: 2019 - 1
      3rd Level: 8 - 1
         Details: Type: web CC, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 25
1st Level: Cash - 2
   2nd Level: 2019 - 2
      3rd Level: 8 - 2
         Details: Type: cash, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 26
         Details: Type: cash, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 27
      3rd Level: 7 - 1
         Details: Type: cash, Year: 2019, Month: 7, ID: 29
   2nd Level: 2000 - 1
      3rd Level: 8 - 1
         Details: Type: cash, Year: 2000, Month: 8, ID: 0
1st Level: Check - 1
   2nd Level: 2019 - 1
      3rd Level: 8 - 1
         Details: Type: check, Year: 2019, Month: 8, ID: 28
```

Comment: This solution is more complicated than required.  You get same results with my one line of code after you sort by type/month.  Grouping just keeps like items together  when you perform a sort.  See my updated code and picture.